# Data structure filtering

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with this structure:

```
const dataset = [
  {
    title: "AA", 
    demos: [
      {name: "aa1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
      {name: "aa2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "aa3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "BB", 
    demos: [
      {name: "bb1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
      {name: "bb2", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "CC", 
    demos: [
      {name: "cc1", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc4", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc5", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
    ]
  }
]
```

So basically an array of level 1 object in which there are a demos array of level 2 objects.

This is want I would like to obtain:

```
const datasetFiltered = [
  {
    title: "AA", 
    demos: [
      {name: "aa2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "aa3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "CC", 
    demos: [
      {name: "cc1", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc4", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
    ]
  }
]
```

I wanto to filter by `toShow` and remove all the object with `toShow = false`. If the level 1 object have all the level 2 objects with `toShow = false`, then I want to remove also the level 1 object.

This is what I tried:

```
const datasetFiltered = dataset.map(level1 => {
  level1.demos = level1.demos.filter(demo => demo.toShow);
  return level1;
});
```

It works but it doesn't remove the level 1 object if it has no children. How can I modify my code?

Comment: Add a second `filter()` on the top level that then filters for `level1.demos.length > 0`?

Comment: what about `'cc5'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, you are right, I updated the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add one more loop and filter out level1 objects with empy demos

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    title: "AA", 
    demos: [
      {name: "aa1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
      {name: "aa2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "aa3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "BB", 
    demos: [
      {name: "bb1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
      {name: "bb2", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "CC", 
    demos: [
      {name: "cc1", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc4", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
      {name: "cc5", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
    ]
  }
]

const datasetFiltered = dataset.map(level1 => {
  level1.demos = level1.demos.filter(demo => demo.toShow);
  return level1;
}).filter(level1 => level1.demos.length); // you can just add one more loop and filter out level1 objects with empy demos

console.log(datasetFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const dataset = [
  {
title: "AA", 
demos: [
  {name: "aa1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
  {name: "aa2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
  {name: "aa3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
]
  },
  {
title: "BB", 
demos: [
  {name: "bb1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
  {name: "bb2", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
]
  },
  {
title: "CC", 
demos: [
  {name: "cc1", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
  {name: "cc2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
  {name: "cc3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
  {name: "cc4", data: [], options: [], toShow: true},
  {name: "cc5", data: [], options: [], toShow: false},
]
  }
]

const datasetFiltered = dataset.map(level1 => {
  level1.demos = level1.demos.filter(demo => demo.toShow);
  
  return level1.demos.length && level1;
}).filter(x => x);

console.log(datasetFiltered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and return an empty array for empty filtered `demos`.

Oterwise return a new object with filtered items.

This approach does not mutate the given data.

```js
const
    data = [{ title: "AA",  demos: [{ name: "aa1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false }, { name: "aa2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }, { name: "aa3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }] }, { title: "BB", demos: [{ name: "bb1", data: [], options: [], toShow: false }, { name: "bb2", data: [], options: [], toShow: false }] }, { title: "CC", demos: [{ name: "cc1", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }, { name: "cc2", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }, { name: "cc3", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }, { name: "cc4", data: [], options: [], toShow: true }, { name: "cc5", data: [], options: [], toShow: false }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(o => {
        const demos = o.demos.filter(({ toShow }) => toShow);
        return demos.length
            ? { ...o, demos }
            : [];
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

also, you can try this:

```
const filteredByToshow = dataset.map(obj => obj.demos).flat().filter(obj =>obj.toShow);
```